# Printing variable value using Reference to const gives different result

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I am learning about references in C++. So i am trying out different examples to better understand the concept. One example that i could not understand is given below:

```
double val = 4.55;
const int &ref = val;
    
std::cout << ref <<std::endl; //prints 4 instead of 4.55
```

I want to know what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: `ref` is bound to a temporary `int` object.

Comment: Can you explain some more.

Comment: Why do you consider the code to have a problem? How can a reference to an int result in anything but an int? C++ is statically typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that the reference `ref` is bound to a temporary object of type `int` that has the value `4`. This is explained in more detail below.

When you wrote:

```
const int &ref = val;
```

a temporary of type `int` with value `4` is created and then the reference `ref` is bound to this temporary `int` object **instead of** binding to the variable `val` directly. This happens because the type of the variable `val` on the right hand side is `double` while on the left hand side you have a **reference to `int`**. But for binding a reference to a variable the types **should match**.

For solving the problem you should write:

```
const double &ref = val; //note int changed to double on the left hand side
```

The above statement means `ref` is a reference to const `double`. This means we cannot change the variable `val` using `ref`.

If you want to be able to change `val` using `ref` then you could simply write:

```
double &ref = val;
```

Comment: Or simply `double& dref = val;` since no temporaries are created in this case.

Comment: @rturrado Yes added that also.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int &ref = val;
```

Here you initialize ref as int type so it holds value of int type so ,Implicit Type Conversion takes place .Read more about type conversion [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-in-c/)